Mac Terminal does not display U+200C Unicode special character correctly
I cannot get Mac Terminal to display U+200C, aka zero-width non-joiner, correctly. Instead, it simply types <200c>.
Unicode settings for the profile I use have been set to UTF-8 as described on this Apple Support page. I am also using a font which has a glyph for this character, as I can test it in Font Book.
Any ideas on how to get Terminal to display this character properly? In case you want to try it, use the below text and see if it appears in your terminal as in the webpage.
می‌روم

(Persian word meaning I'm going).
P.S. Let me know if you happen to know another terminal on any other platform which might correctly display this character.

If I assign that string to a variable and then echo the variable, I get what looks like the right output. Is that what you're doing?

Strangely enough, I get the right output.

To be more specific, I see this at first: str='می<200c>روم', but when I run echo $str, it correctly displays: می‌روم. How can I get it to display correctly in the first place?

Like you both, (UTF-8 enabled) directly pasting the characters I get the wrong output, but assigning to a variable, it's shown correctly as per OP's example above when echoed. Interestingly I also tried using iTerm and while a straightforward paste also shows `<200c>, the character order looks different. Also assigning to a variable in iTerm 'works' but the 'correct' output isn't in the correct order again. OP, might you experiment with iTerm as well and see if that offers a new perspective on what may be happening?

I don't know that you can, but is that really a problem?

I tried iTerm 2 as well, and the result is same as yours.

The thing is, I encountered this problem when trying to edit a file in Vim that included U+200C. Apparently, it wasn't displayed correctly. I had set everything in Vim to UTF-8 and even enabled bidirectional text (as Persian is right-to-left). Everything looked perfect except for <200c>. I realized the terminal is somewhat incapable of displaying it. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Maybe you would find something here: https://github.com/vimpersian/vimpersian.github.io

@AndyGriffiths That's more like the line editor in whatever shell you're using not knowing what to do with it when you type it.  But it gets assigned to the variable correctly and when the terminal outputs it, it's the right glyph.

@MarcWilson Very good point. Didn't consider that and suppose it answers OP too.

@LincDavis, thank you very much. I had been unaware of the webpage you shared. It was quite helpful.

This is the line editor in whatever shell you're using mangling the text.
Here are a couple of examples.
In ksh (my default shell):
$ TEXT="می^⁌روم"
$ echo $TEXT
می‌روم
$

Notice, no garbage.
Note that bash doesn't have the problem either.
$ bash
$ TEXT="می‌روم"
$ echo $TEXT
می‌روم
$ 

Now, in zsh:
$ zsh
% TEXT="می<200c>روم"
% echo $TEXT
می‌روم
% 

Note the garbage for the first character.  But the string is in the variable, so Terminal outputs it correctly.

I just noticed that ksh didn't deal with it correctly either when I pasted it, but it echoed it correctly.  Guess that wasn't the best example although it doesn't print an escape. ^_^

Can concur that bash works correctly when pasted, and works as expected (L to R) when backspace is used. Here's the issue reported on the zsh mailing list, but it didn't get much traction or a solution. https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00789.html

Thanks @MarcWilson. I now realize the problem had to do with the shell. But my original problem – Vim not displaying U+200C correctly – still remains, even if I open Vim after invoking bash. Do you think I should open a new question on Vim Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?

It turns out it has already been asked and answered here.

If you've solved the problem, please post the solution as an answer here and accept it. By the way, vim has its own line editor and doesn't use the one provided by the shell.

I think Vim is saying "we know, it's not a bug, here's what to do to minimize it".
